# Insert reference to pointer into an map

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
struct A
{
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new A;
  std::unordered_map<int, A*&> hash;

  hash.insert(make_pair(1, a)); //error
}
```

What is the syntax to make this work?

If I do this:

```
a = new A;
```

I want the `hashmap` to point to the new object.

Comment: And… what is the actual error?

Comment: Are you sure that you want your map point to the *address of the local variable `a`*?  Wouldn't it suffice to store the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the return type of `std::make_pair` is `std::pair<int, A*>` instead of `std::pair<int, A*&>` (due to template argument deduction).

This [does the trick](http://ideone.com/dxHMn):

```
hash.insert(std::make_pair<int, A*&>(1, a)); //no error
```

Note that it is uncommon to store references to maps and other data structures. Think if you really need it.

Comment: I am using vs 2010 and still get the error:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(163): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'A *' to 'A *&'

Comment: It's not only uncommon, it is illegal to store a reference in a map. A reference is not an object.

Comment: so the solution is to do:
std::map<int, A**> hash;
and then for example 
(*hash[0])->func();

Comment: @Memi - That is extremely dangerous, as it requires `a` to still be there when you call the function. Will it?

Comment: @Bo Persson- I am aware that it is dangerous, but for example if a is class member and it will not be deleted until class is destructed, it should be ok:). And if someone put it to null the program should crach.

Answer (score 0):

hash.insert(**std::pair< int , A*&>**(1, a));

Answer (score 0):

This question misses the point of [value-semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics) that is inherent in the design of STL.

Value-semantics implies

**Values are stored and copied into containers (including pointers), not references.**

When you insert something into a container, a copy is made and stored, even if what you pass in is a reference variable.

*This implies you can't have constructs like a std::vector<> of references.*

In your specific example, omit the reference symbol (&) and you are fine (besides the memory leak).
Storing a pointer in stl is cheap so you don't have to worry about cost of copying the pointer.

**But, as always in C++, you do have to concern yourself with cleanup (if you don't use smart pointers) and object lifetimes.**